# To what extent were the information, statistics and updates told to the public of the British and German homefronts accurate and reliable?

Tags: world-war-one, historiography

My focus question is, as it says in the title above, about whether what was presented to the public on Germany and Britain's home fronts during the First World War was actually true, or was it presented in a very biased way depending on the country, was it made to appear that not as many people were dying and they were very successful? Did they lie about the conditions and injuries that the troops were facing? What do relevant up to date sources say about the accuracy of contemporary reports?

Comment: A request for sources is off topic on History SE.

Comment: @TomAu Sorry, I'm new to History SE, can you recommend a site where I can ask for sources?

Comment: You might try Quora. Such a site doesn't exist on Stack Exchange at this time, although they are developing new sites all the time. In some years, there may even be a data and source site, SE who knows. But not today.

Comment: I took the liberty of recasting your question as "historiography." It may (or may not) "fly" in its current form.